# Android tablet as a second display - NOT wifi just via USB-C

Tags: android, samsung, usb-c

I was looking for a solution to connect my tablet as a second screen and my laptop with Ubuntu via USB-C. I found some solutions in this forum, but only with Wi-Fi connection.

Details:

- Tablet Samsung s7 fe
- Laptop Samsung Galaxy book pro 360
- Cable USB-C to USB-C (Mcdodo CA7131)

My display settings:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No, it can't be done. Your tablet has no video input. The solutions via WiFi you mention are actually remote desktop sharing.

Comment: If you [share internet from PC to android via USB](https://askubuntu.com/q/1000098/349837) you could then use something like [Deskreen](https://github.com/pavlobu/deskreen/)